# Visiting Entity Framework's Include method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to visit the Entity Framework's Include method using `QueryResultCache` class which is [motioned here](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/caching-the-results-of-linq-queries/). It's a very popular article and a lot of query caching libraries are using it.
When I try an expression like:

```
var exp1 = context.Products.Include(x => x.Tags)
                   .Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => y.Name.Contains("Test")))
                   .Select(x => new {x.ProductId}).Expression;
```

with it, it produces this string:

```
value(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1
[EfSecondLevelCaching.Test.Models.Product]).MergeAs(AppendOnly).IncludeSpan
(value(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Span))
.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => y.Name.Contains("Test")))
.Select(x => new <>f__AnonymousType5`1(ProductId = x.ProductId))
```

As you can see, the result doesn't contain the parameters of `Include` method (x => x.Tags). So most of the linq caching libraries on the net can't create a valid unique query key for the EF queries. How can I fix this?

Edit:

If I remove the select method, it will produce:

```
value(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1
[EfSecondLevelCaching.Test.Models.Product])
    .MergeAs(AppendOnly)
    .IncludeSpan(value(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Span))
    .Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => y.Name.Contains("Test")))
```

So here there is no difference between `Include(x=>x.Tags)` and `Include(x=>x.Users)`.

Comment: Just an idea, but you could include the "Tags" property in your select at the end.
So you have .Select(x=>new {x.ProductId, x.Tags}).Expression;

Comment: @MohesnKahn As Andy says in his answer, try just context.Products.Include(x => x.Tags)
                   .Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => y.Name.Contains("Test"))).Expression;

Answer (score 0):

The query will only return what is in your Select expression. In this case `Select(x => new {x.ProductId})` means that only a single field `ProductId` will be returned.

Your `Include` would have made a difference if you were returning `Products` as they contain `Tags`, but makes no difference if you just have `ProductId`.

See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx) for more information on eager loading (`Include` ensures eager loading)

Comment: That makes total sense.

Comment: That's true, but this is just an example to show the concept. Removing the select method, doesn't change the `IncludeSpan` part.